# Sending zipfile of images from AWS lambda, getting error Unable to marshal response: <zipfile.ZipFile> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to zip and return a file with images from a lambda (that is fetched from s3).
I'm getting this error `Unable to marshal response: <zipfile.ZipFile [closed]> is not JSON serializable` with the below code. Is there another, working, way of doing things?

Thanks!

```
def get_zipped_files(files):
    files = files.split(',')
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    bucket = 'my_bucket'
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zipper:
        for file in files:
            infile_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)
            infile_content = infile_object['Body'].read()
            zipper.writestr(file, infile_content)
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'files': zipper
    }
    return response
```

Comment: Basically you can’t return the zipped object in json. Try looking up how to either send file type objects or how to serialize the zip file object into a string of bytes.

Comment: Yea I'm looking at different ways but weirdly I haven't found that much. Seems like a pretty common use case to me

Comment: I haven’t work with lambda before. I know flask has a separate response object for files